# Do I need to chmod 777 mounted volumes?

Tags: permissions, mount, chmod

I have an openstack VM with the following users:

```
[foo@influxdb ~]$ id root
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)

[foo@influxdb ~]$ id foo
uid=500(foo) gid=500(foo) groups=500(foo),10(wheel)

[foo@influxdb ~]$ id influxdb
uid=498(influxdb) gid=498(influxdb) groups=498(influxdb)
```

I have the following mount point:

```
mkfs.ext4 /dev/vdb
mkdir /mtn/bar
mount /dev/vdb /mnt/bar
echo "/dev/vdb /mnt/bar ext4 defaults 0 0" >> /etc/fstab
```

What is the 'proper' way to make it so that the influxdb user can read and write from the volume?

Two, less-than-ideal methods I can think of are:

```
chmod 777
chown root:influxdb /mnt/bar
```

Should I make a 'volumes' group and then `chown root:volumes` and `useradd -G volumes influxdb`? What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Do not `chmod 777` the volume, this is very bad practice and has serious security implications. If you need multiple users to be able to read and write to that volume, then the simple solution is as you suggest to create a shared group. Just ensure all group members umasks are set to 002 so all created files will be writable to the group and directories will be executable to the group. Slightly more complicated is ACL's, however, I am not sure that is required with the examples you have given.

Answer (score 2):

Really all that is needed is to make sure that there is a directory in /mnt/bar that is writable by the influxdb user

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/bar/influxdb
sudo chown influxdb:influxdb /mnt/bar/influxdb
```

Only root and influxdb will be able to write to it.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to have the user-influxdb for rw, you can chmod with 755! The disturbing  point with 777 is that user has the control over anything in that mount point.